# Dynamically reference to merged/unmerged cell (Google Spreadsheets)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

For example, I have

```
        A         B        C
   +---------+--------+---------+
 1 | Hello   | Google |  Sheets | // original text.
   +---------+--------+---------+
 2 |         |        |         |
   +---------+--------+---------+
```

I would like to reference data from row `1` to row `2`

```
        A         B        C
   +---------+--------+---------+
 1 | Hello   | Google |  Sheets | // original text.
   +---------+--------+---------+
 2 | Hello   | Google |  Sheets | // use formulas to reference data from row 1.
   +---------+--------+---------+
```

And in case that cells `A1:C1` is merged, I would like keep data on row `2` in either this form:

```
        A         B        C
   +---------+---------+---------+
 1 |     Hello Google Sheets     | // original text.
   +---------+---------+---------+
 2 | Hello G | Hello G | Hello G | // use formulas to reference data from row 1.
   | oogle S | oogle S | oogle S |
   | heets   | heets   | heets   |
   +---------+---------+---------+
```

or this form:

```
        A         B        C
   +---------+---------+---------+
 1 |     Hello Google Sheets     | // original text.
   +---------+---------+---------+
 2 |     Hello Google Sheets     | // use formulas to reference data from row 1.
   +---------+---------+---------+
```

*note that row `2` is automatically merged due to change from row `1`.

I'm not sure if there is any way to do this because normally the result is turned out this way:

```
        A         B        C
   +---------+--------+---------+
 1 |      Hello Google Sheets   | // original text.
   +---------+--------+---------+
 2 | Hello G |        |         | // use formulas to reference data from row 1.
   | oogle S |        |         |
   | heets   |        |         |
   +---------+--------+---------+
```

*because `B1` and `C1` is merged by cell `A1`, then cells `B2` and `C2` will just reference to nothing.

Comment: Is it always the same number of words as columns? I don't really understand why your desired text is broken into "Hello G", "oogle S" and "heets". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: "Hello G", "oogle S" and "heets", they are in the same cell and in the single line.

Comment: The main point is not about number of words. It's about how to make row 2 reference to row 1 dynamically.

Comment: Oh so when they are merged all reference A1 and if they're not they reference A1, A2 and A3?

Comment: Yes, normally they reference to A1, A2, A3. The problem is when A1:A3 are merged, B2, B3 will be blank as the last example. I want my spreadsheet to behave like the third or fourth table above.